# Expected Average Completed Tasks for a person per Month Excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

I might be overthinking this, but I want to be able to tell the business what a staff member should be expected to complete per month, using Excel.  The dataset looks like the below:

| Row | Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D | Col E | Col F | Col G | Col H | Col I | Col J | Col K | Col L | Col M | Col N | Col O | Col P | Col Q |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **Name** | **Jan-18** | **Feb-18** | **Mar-18** | **Apr-18** | **May-18** | **Jun-18** | **Jul-18** | **Aug-18** | **Sep-18** | **Oct-18** | **Nov-18** | **Dec-18** | **2018 Total** | **Months worked in 2018** | **% Year worked in 2018** | **Monthly Completions Avg** |
| 2 | Micky Mouse | 10 | 9 | 9 | 3 | 10 | 7 | 8 | 6 | 6 | 4 | 5 | 3 | 80 | 12 | 100% | 6.7 |
| 3 | Donald Duck | 8 | 8 | 5 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 43 | 12 | 100% | 3.6 |
| 4 | Daffy Duck | 9 | 7 | 8 | 11 | 11 | 9 | 14 | 8 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 6 | 85 | 12 | 100% | 7.1 |
| 5 | Tom | 7 | 11 | 20 | 12 | 16 | 8 | 1 | 6 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 88 | 12 | 100% | 7.4 |
| 6 | Jerry | 4 | 1 | 10 | 6 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 41 | 12 | 100% | 3.5 |
| 7 | Homer Simpson | 2 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 7 | 2 | 10 | 6 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 44 | 12 | 100% | 3.7 |
| 8 | Marge Simpson |  |  |  | 2 | 3 | 2 | 15 | 8 | 10 | 6 | 5 | 10 | 61 | 9 | 75% | 6.8 |
| 9 | Lisa Simpson |  |  |  |  | 2 | 6 | 15 | 18 | 4 | 8 | 3 | 3 | 59 | 8 | 67% | 7.4 |

I can show the average, per month, per person (end column).  But, if a new person started, what would I tell the business what that persons expected monthly average should be, based on the existing members of staff?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you could mean: `=(SUMPRODUCT(Q2:Q9,O2:O9)/SUM(O2:O9))/12*O10` where the assumption is that given data starts at `A1` and `O10` consists the number of months for the new employee.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be sum(2018 Total)/sum(Months worked in 2018) ?

Comment: Ate you asking for the average across all?  Or what you should tell the business for a new starter?  The first is fairly simple the second should be based on business knowledge

Comment: In order to answer this question, you first need to make some reasonable starting assumption. E.g. that the average for the new person will be the same as the average across all existing people. Let us know what assumption / model you are going with.

Comment: I am looking to make an assumption that the average for a new person will be the same as the average across all existing people.  My initial thoughts were that it would be the sum of the year total divided by the sum of the months worked by everyone. Although SUMPRODUCT is a good idea, does it sum up averages and is that bad? (SUMPRODUCT(Q2:Q9,O2:O9)/SUM(O2:O9)) comes out with 5.67 and SUM(N2:N9)/SUM(O2:O9) comes out with 5.63  Which one would be the correct method, or is it something else?